How to Minify CSS for Improved Load Times on Sitecore Cloud
I've run a performance analysis on my Sitecore Cloud-hosted site and found that there is a potential savings of 4 KiB if the CSS file is minified. The analysis points to a specific CSS file with a transfer size of 15.3 KiB, indicating that minification could be beneficial.
Attached is a screenshot from the performance report.
I'm seeking guidance on the best approach to achieve this within the Sitecore Cloud environment. Specifically, I would like to know:
How can I access and modify CSS files on Sitecore Cloud?
Is there an automated process or tool within Sitecore that can handle CSS minification?
Are there best practices or recommended workflows for managing and optimizing static resources such as CSS on Sitecore Cloud?
Any advice or insights from the community would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

